# Solve a time-dependent matrix DE using NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, matrix

I am trying to numerically solve a time-dependent matrix DE using *Mathematica*. However, it seems that *Mathematica* freezes even for two-dimensional matrix equations.

For example, we have:

$$\frac{d}{dt} A(t)=M(t)A(t)+A_0$$

where $M(t)=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & t \\ t & -1 \end{pmatrix}$ and $A_0=A(0) = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$.

For this problem, the simple code below runs forever until *Mathematica* freezes:

```
m[t_] = ({{1, t}, {t, -1}}); A0 = ({{1, 0}, {0, 1}});
sA = NDSolveValue[{A'[t] == m[t].A[t] + A0, A[0] == A0}, A, {t, 0, 1}]
```

I know I can always write it as a $4\times4$ coupled ODEs, but for even slightly higher dimensions the process would be tedious and ugly. Can anyone help?

Comment: The equation in your $\TeX$ expression is not the same as the one you are trying to solve in the code. Trying `NDSolveValue[{A'[t] == m[t].A[t], A[0] == A0}, A, {t, 0, 1}]` works fine, so which one did you actually need?

Comment: Thanks for reminding me of the inconsistency. In fact, I want to solve the inhomogeneous time-dependent matrix DE. I've edited my latex equations.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem is that `Dot` does not evaluate if one of the arguments is not a list of some sort, and so when the matrix `A0` is added, it does something you might not foresee. Consider:

```
m = {{1, t}, {t, -1}};
A0 = {{1, 0}, {0, 1}};
m.A[t] + A0
(* {
  { 1 + {{1, t}, {t, -1}}.A[t], {{1, t}, {t, -1}}.A[t] }
  , { {{1, t}, {t, -1}}.A[t], 1 + {{1, t}, {t, -1}}.A[t] }
 } *)
```

which is the same as

```
(* {
  {1 + m.A[t], m.A[t]}
  , {m.A[t], 1 + m.A[t]}
 } *)
```

That is clearly not the right expression and is a consequence of the fact that `Plus` automatically threads over its arguments (as pointed out by `Michael E2`), whereas `Dot` remains unevaluated if given symbolic arguments.

Instead, I did this:

```
m = {{1, t}, {t, -1}};
A0 = {{1, 0}, {0, 1}};
funcs = Array[A[#1, #2][t] &, {2, 2}]
equations = Flatten@Join[
  Thread[D[funcs, t] == m.funcs + A0]
  , Thread[funcs == A0 /. t -> 0]
 ]
sA = NDSolveValue[equations, funcs, {t, 0, 1}]
Plot[sA, {t, 0, 1}]
```

resulting in

[image]

This allows you to generalize to arbitrary dimensions by playing around with the `{2, 2}` in the definition of `funcs`. Reconstruct the matrix `A[t]` by doing

```
Partition[sA, 2]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what I need. To my understanding, we basically need to treat each matrix element as a function of time and solve the DE. We can use the matrix manipulation to simplify our tedious algebra. This is because NDSolve process does not treat A[t] as a matrix for the matrix operation. Is it correct?

Comment: @K.Qu. Almost. As pointed out by Marco B in a comment above, without the source term `A1`, the code works, for reasons basically outlined by Michael E2 in his answer. I tend to get around possible issues like this by solving for the matrix elements rather than the matrix.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `Plus` will thread symbolic terms, such as `m[t].A[t]`, over explicit arrays, such as `A0`.  One needs all terms to be of the same kind, either all symbolic or all explicit arrays.  To code up the symbolic alternative, one can either use [`DiscreteVariables`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiscreteVariables.html) or code the constant term as a `NumericQ`-protected constant function.

```
m[t_] = {{1, t}, {t, -1}};
Clear[A0];
A0 = ({{1, 0}, {0, 1}});
sys = {A'[t] == m[t].A[t] + B[t],
   A[0] == A0, B[0] == A0};
{sA} = NDSolve[sys, A, {t, 0, 1}, DiscreteVariables -> {B}];

Clear[A0];
A0[t_?NumericQ] = {{1, 0}, {0, 1}};
sys = {A'[t] == m[t].A[t] + A0[t],
   A[0] == A0[0]};
{sNA} = NDSolve[sys, A, {t, 0, 1}];
```

I would have guessed that the `DiscreteVariables` approach would be easier for `NDSolve` to analyze and might produce better results, but in this case the results are identical.

```
sA === sNA
(*  True  *)
```

With this approach the solution is matrix-valued, which might be an advantage, or not, depending on the applications.  It is not an advantage in plotting the components of the matrix:

```
Plot[A[t] /. sA // Evaluate, {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This is an interesting approach. It forces all the matrices to be explicitly time dependent. I wonder if there is a systematically explanation about the manipulations of matrix or array? I got so confused when a matrix is mixed with functions.