# d-dimensional compiled function in NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, compile

Based on this answer, I understand how to use a one dimensional compiled function in NDSolve. [Mathematica NDSolve and 'Compile'?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13287/mathematica-ndsolve-and-compile)

I'd like to be able to use a d-dimensional compiled function `f`, in the same way. 
`f` would be a vector-valued function which returns a vector, somthing like this:

```
f = Compile[{{x, _Real, 1}}, x]
```

But imagine that it's costly to evaluate.

I've dreamed up some syntax which I know doesn't work, but which kind of says what I want to happen:

```
rhs[x_?VectorQ[#, NumericQ]] := f[x] 
NDSolve[Join[Thread[Table[x[i]'[t],{i,d}]-rhs[Table[x[i][t],{i,d}]]==0],initialconditions], Table[x[i][t],{i,d}], {t, 0, 1}]
```

I know that the above code won't work, because Mathematica won't know how to add together the vector of derivatives and the `rhs` function until it's been evaluated numerically.

Does anybody know a syntax which works correctly for this?

Note that I can't just break down the vector function `f` into d separate functions; it's costly to evaluate and I need to make sure that `f` is called only once each time its components are accessed for a given value of x.

Comment: Examples: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14407/ndsolve-with-vectors,
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/93986/solve-a-time-dependent-matrix-de-using-ndsolve

Comment: `NDSolve[{x'[t] == f[t], x[0] == array}, x, {t, 0, 1},...]` where `array` is of dim. `d`.

Comment: Oh that's much more simple than I thought. Thanks Michael.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several questions on the site that ask about or deal with array-valued variables in differential equations, especially `NDSolve`/`NDSolveValue`. They involve other issues as well, and this question puts the basic problem quite simply and clearly.  For instance, we can use the "vector-valued solution" from [this Q&A](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/134222/easy-way-to-plot-ode-solutions-from-ndsolve) as an [MWE](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2126/what-do-we-mean-by-a-self-contained-minimal-working-example).

Here's a complete example:

```
d = 4;  (* dimension *)
rhs[t_, x_?(VectorQ[#, NumericQ] &)] := (Cos[Range[d] t] *
    AdjacencyMatrix@CycleGraph[d, DirectedEdges -> True]).x - x + 1;
sol = NDSolve[{x'[t] == rhs[t, x[t]], x[0] == Range[d]}, x, {t, 0, 2}];
```

The solution consists of 73 steps, the value at each step a 4-vector:

```
x["ValuesOnGrid"] /. First@sol // Dimensions
(*  {73, 4}  *)
```

One constraint of the solution is that evaluating it at, say, `t=1.5`, results in getting all four components.

```
x[1.5] /. First[sol]
(*  {1.94518, 1.23931, 1.10914, 1.54423}  *)
```

So to use the solution takes manipulation. For instance, an easy (if less well-known) way to get a plot is this (from [the same Q&A](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/134222/easy-way-to-plot-ode-solutions-from-ndsolve)):

```
ListLinePlot[
 Transpose[{Flatten[x["Grid"] /. sol], #}] & /@
  (Transpose[x["ValuesOnGrid"]] /. First@sol), 
 PlotLegends -> Array[Inactive[Part][x, #] &, x["OutputDimensions"] /. First@sol]]
```

[image]

To get the value of a particular coordinate, one cannot simply execute `x[1.5][[1]] /. First@sol`, because `x[1.5][[1]]` is evaluated to `1.5` first: the next step becomes `1.5 /. First@sol`, which does not give the value of `x`.  Instead, one can get the order of evaluation right or use `Indexed`:

```
(x[1.5] /. First@sol)[[1]]
Indexed[x[1.5], 1] /. First@sol
(*  1.94518  *)
```

Alternatively, one can reconstruct the individual coordinate functions from `sol`, which again requires some array gymnastics:

```
compSol = With[{data = Hold[Transpose[{x["Grid"], ##}] & @@@ 
    Transpose[{x["ValuesOnGrid"], x'["ValuesOnGrid"]}, {2, 3, 1}]] /. First@sol},
  Interpolation /@ ReleaseHold@data]
(* results in a list of 4 InterpolationFunction[]'s *)

ListLinePlot@compSol
(* gives the same graph as above (without the legend) *)

compSol[[1]]@ 1.5  (* evaluate first component at 1.5 *)
(*  1.94518  *)
```